# adding www. to img src

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin that accepts an image in a textbox and outputs it without the www. inthe src. So it looks like this:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/my_img.png" alt="" />
```

But I need it to render client side like this:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/images/my_img.png" alt="" />
```

Apparently they claim without the www the images don't show up, even thought I have tested this site in every computer I have gotten my hands on and looks fine.

I added the following to my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but no cigar.

Does anyone know how I can add the www. to the src="url" programmatically or even  a plugin?

Thank you

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen sounds like wordpress.

Comment: the website owners. It's a website I did for a friend at church and I told him I'd make it with wordpress so that I can be quick and effortless about it, instead of coding it from scratch like I would with a client. If I had done that I would had more control over the code obviously (as opposed to plugins) but , like I said, it was supposed to be a template, some plugins and mostly front end development

Comment: @Pachonk yes, hence the wordpress tag. I guess I should have disclosed that. I thought since I tagged it that way, only wordpress developers would get attention of it...edit (actually my first sentence does disclose it is a wordpress site) ;)

Comment: I'm wondering if there was a quick shortcut I could use in the function.php file or something like that. You'd be surprised what some wordpress developers can do

Comment: @LOTUSMS => See this Post http://www.htaccessbasics.com/force-www-nonwww-domain/

Comment: @AmitThakur I already did that. It was the first thing I thought of. (you can see it in my question) it works on the domain, not the images.

Comment: perhaps a way to add it to the database? Wordpress stores their content in a MySQL database. Worst case scenario, I'll go and add it manually but maybe there is a query that I can write to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a filter on the media url with the `wp_get_attachment_url` hook:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'add_www_to_images_url');
function add_www_to_images_url($url) {
    // if there's no www already, add it
    if(false === strpos($url, '//www'))
        return str_replace('//', '//www.', $url);
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: This was a nice and worthy try, but unfortunately, it didn't do it. I had hopes. The code makes sense

Comment: maybe adding the name of plugin used to the question could help

Comment: It's pretty late on my side of town.  But I'll pick up in the morning.  Thanks

Comment: My code doesn't work with images already loaded probably because the plugin saved the "wrong" absolute images urls (without www) in postmetas. It should work with new images. For the old ones you could re-choose the images for every member and save, or, if they're too many, make a function that for each member updates the postmeta desired.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I knew there was something out there for this. Thanks pal!